# Is there a trigger limit for Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I plan to watch a Firebase database node for create/delete and reflect that to another database node using Cloud Functions.

Is there a limit for such an operation? For example assume 10000 nodes added at once which should trigger 10000 inserts somewhere else, is this acceptable?

**UPDATE:**

I see these limits in [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) section:
`Max concurrent invocations for a background function` and `Max invocation rate for a background function`

Does that mean if I make more than 1000 requests, rest (9000 for the example above) gets disregarded or just gets slower to finish them all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rate limits won't drop events.  If they did, that would be exceptionally bad, and your app would not scale.

Rate limits are in place to prevent a massive update from spinning up potentially millions of instances concurrently.  Instead, Cloud Functions will limit the maximum **concurrent** number of invocations, and force all the events to go through that max instead of trying to handle them all at the same time.  The events will be processed as fast as your function can deal with them, within that concurrent maximum.

Comment: #Doug Stevenson
do you know if for example I have for example 40K onCreate like: functions.database.ref('/usersAnswers/{gameId}').onCreate(event => ...
That will be called but only this function will run this is the limit that firebase talked about?